# Morphisms and objects of the $\mathbb{SET}$?

Tags: soft-question, category-theory

Whenever there is a morphism $f : A \mapsto B$ and $g : B \mapsto C$, there **must exist** $A \mapsto C$ = $g \circ f$. That's a reasonable requirement.

However, I am a programmer and mostly deal with $\mathbb{SET}$: category of sets and single-variable functions between them.

It seems to be special. I'll give you an example: let's fix some $X \in Obj(\mathbb{SET})$. If I am not mistaken, $\forall Y \in Obj(\mathbb{SET}): \forall y \in Y: \exists f: X \mapsto Y$ defined as a constant function that maps entire $X$ to a particular $y \in Y$. It works in exactly the same way as a constant functor to a fixed object of a target category.

**Now the tricky part**: there is a set of functions $\{ X \mapsto Y \}$ for all $X, Y$ and **each such set is an object of the $\mathbb{SET}$**. Hence, there exists a **morphism** $m: X \rightarrow Y$ and there exists yet another morphism $M : X \rightarrow \{ X \mapsto Y \}$. Now, assume there also exists a morphism $k: Y \rightarrow Y'$. It would be reasonable to immidiately reuqire existence of $M' : M \rightarrow \{ X \mapsto Y' \}$ defined as $X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow Y'$ path in the $\mathbb{SET}$. So end up with:
$X \rightarrow \{ X \mapsto Y \} \rightarrow \{ X \mapsto Y' \}$, which, by the requirement I've started from, yields an $X \rightarrow \{ X \mapsto Y' \}$ moprhism.

$\mathbb{SET}$ seems to be very special. When some $x \in X$ is lifted to a $X \mapsto Y$ in the abovementioned fashion, you kind of appear at two different places at the same time: on the one hand, you get a particular element of an appropariate $\{ X \mapsto Y \}$; on the other hand - lifting takes you to a $\{  X \mapsto Y \}$ - **an object of the $\mathbb{SET}$**.

So my quesiton is kind of soft - doest it blur razor-sharp edges between morphisms and objects within the same category? Is it really that special or I am I just overreacting?

Comment: The only thing special about $Set$ is that $Hom(X,Y)$ is again a set for any two sets $X,Y$. Which is not ultimately special, the same happens for example in vector spaces. What you've discovered is functoriality of $Hom$.

Comment: It looks like you're noticing mainly that $\mathbf{Set}$ is [cartesian closed](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cartesian+closed+category)--i.e. you can curry functions whose domains are finite products.